# How do I update AWS Lambda function using CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I want to deploy and update my lambda function code using CloudFormation Template.

My deployment workflow are:

1. Compress my lambda function code into a zip file called `Lambda`
2. Enabling s3 versioning of the s3 bucket called `LambdaS3`
3. Upload the zip file into s3 bucket called `LambdaS3`
4. Upload the CloudFormation template `CFtemplate` as below into the s3bucket `LambdaS3`
5. Create the CloudFormation stack by entering "LambdaS3" as parameter `LambdaS3`,
   "Lambda" as parameter `Lambdafilename` and the version of the zip file as the parameter `LambdafileVersion`

My lambda code update workflow are:

1. Compress my updated lambda function code into a zip file called `Lambda`
2. Upload the updated zip file into the s3 bucket called `LambdaS3`
3. Update the CloudFormation stack by entering the updated version of the zip file as the parameter `LambdafileVersion`

- What I expected: deployment and update will be successful
- Actual result: Get the message from AWS "There was an error creating this change set
  The submitted information didn't contain changes. Submit different information to create a change set." during updating the stack, while deployment is successful.

My template is as below

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Metadata: ""
Description: ""
Parameters:

  LambdaS3:
    Description: Api Gateway Authorizer Lambda S3Bucket Name
    Type: String

  Lambdafilename:
    Description: Api Gateway Authorizer Lambda file Name (Latest)
    Type: String

  LambdafileVersion:
    Description: Lambda zip file version
    Type: String

Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Resources:
  LambdaFunction:
    DeletionPolicy: "Delete"
    Type: "AWS::Serverless::Function"
    Properties:
      Description: ""
      FunctionName: "LambdaFunction"
      Handler: "lambda_function.lambda_handler"
      CodeUri:
        Bucket: !Ref LambdaS3
        Key: !Sub '${Lambdafilename}.zip'
        Version: !Ref LambdafileVersion
      MemorySize: 512
      Role: !GetAtt IAMRole2.Arn
      Runtime: "python3.8"
      Timeout: 20
      Tracing: "PassThrough"
      AutoPublishAlias: live
      DeploymentPreference:
        Type: Linear10PercentEvery10Minutes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work because you are using CodeDeploy. If you want to update  functions they way you are trying, then you have to remove the following from your code:

```
      AutoPublishAlias: live
      DeploymentPreference:
        Type: Linear10PercentEvery10Minutes
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I can update the code now! However ```AutoPublishAlias: live``` can be kept after my trial. Is there any reason why CodeDeploy cannot be incorporated in my template?

Comment: @KenLEE I'm not sure about CodeDeploy. You can make new question about that. Acceptance of my answers this, and previous one, would be appreciated.

Comment: then how do you think of this solution(remove the two properties)? (I am just curious)